# Why my scipy.optimize.minimize fails?

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I try with  fmin_bfgs to find the local minimum of the absolute function `abs(x)`. The initial point is set to 100.0; the expected answer is 0.0. However, I get:

```
In [184]: op.fmin_bfgs(lambda x:np.abs(x),100.0)
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 100.000000
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 64
         Gradient evaluations: 20
Out[184]: array([100.0])
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods like fmin_bfgs and fmin_slsqp require smooth (continuous derivative) functions in order to provide reliable results.  abs(x) has a dicontinuous derivative at its minimum.  A method like the Nelder-Mead simplex, which doesn't require continuous derivatives, might provide better results in this case.

Comment: This solved my problem too, thanks. I've asked a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36110998/3904031)